# Why does "move" command give an error if there aren't any files

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a simple **move** command I would like to run often to move some files if they are present.

```
Move MyDir1\*.foo MyDir2
```

Right now the bat file I have made exits with an error because there often isn't any *.foo in the directory and my system really dislikes that.

Is there some kind of toggle so **move** just does nothing if files are not present.

Any alternative is welcome, **move** was just the command that came to mind.

Comment: Post your entire script. By itself, move doesn’t do anything but report an error. What you do with it from there decides what your batch file does.

Answer (score 1):

ok, guess it may be by design, so I just wrapped it

```
@echo off
IF EXIST *.foo (
move MyDir1\*.Foo MyDir2
) ELSE (
echo nothing today
)
```